# django_markdown failed to show preview in django 1.9

Tags: django, django-admin, django-views, markdown

In trying to integrate `django_markdown` in django admin panel. After creating a post when preview button is clicked it shows the following error in console.

Here is the traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/markdown/preview/

Django Version: 1.9
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blog',
 'ckeditor',
 'django_markdown']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\X\test_django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\X\test_django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\X\test_django\lib\site-packages\django_markdown\views.py" in preview
  22.             content=request.REQUEST.get('data', 'No content posted'),

Exception Type: AttributeError at /markdown/preview/
Exception Value: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'REQUEST'
```

Please guide me how to correct it.

Comment: @Alasdair i fixed the issue and sent a pull request

Comment: I didn't downvote, but somebody else might have downvoted because you posted a screenshot. Screenshots are harder to read, and it's harder for future users to find the question because they can't search the text.

Comment: question updated with trackback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the workaround

Open `views.py` inside folder `django_markdown`.

Open the file `views.py` and go to `line 22`, and change the following line

```
content=request.REQUEST.get('data', 'No content posted'),
```

to this

```
content=request.POST.get('data', 'No content posted'),
```

Answer (score 2):

[`request.REQUEST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.REQUEST) was deprecated in Django 1.7, and removed in Django 1.9.

To work with Django 1.9, the django_markdown app needs to be updated so that it doesn't use request.REQUEST any more.

Comment: I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/klen/django_markdown/issues/57) on Github. If you want to use the preview view, you'll need to wait for it to be fixed, or patch it yourself.